# Why does RFC 2181 disallow MX record with a CNAME exchange?

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, cname-record, rfc

According to RFC 2181 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181#section-10.3

> 10.3. MX and NS records
>
> The domain name used as the value of a NS resource record, or part
> of    the value of a MX resource record must not be an alias.  Not
> only is    the specification clear on this point, but using an alias
> in either    of these positions neither works as well as might be
> hoped, nor well    fulfills the ambition that may have led to this
> approach.  This    domain name must have as its value one or more
> address records.    Currently those will be A records, however in the
> future other record    types giving addressing information may be
> acceptable.  It can also    have other RRs, but never a CNAME RR.

Why is this restriction in place?

I assume due to resolving overhead but is it really that costly nowadays?

From experience with an incorrect MX record that used a CNAME exchange no problems were experienced during the course of a couple years except for a couple mail relays that couldn't find the MX exchange.

Comment: The next two paragraphs explain it.

Comment: *no problems were experienced (...) except for a couple mail relays that couldn't find the MX exchange.* -- This is the classic straw man for standards violation. Some software may elect to be tolerant of a violation, but that's the standards equivalent of [Unspecified Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior). If your software needs it in order to function, it's not good software. Also, these attempts are generally considered "best effort": it might not be able to work *all the time*, which goes to Michael's point.

Comment: @AndrewB I agree. I meant that as with many other DNS resolvers being tolerant of the error I'm more curious why it's still prohibited. I assume it's just unnecessary to use a CNAME as the value.

Comment: Sorry, you caught me mid-edit. Putting my comment together with Michael's: *some software may try to work around the problem, but there is no guarantee that it will always be successful due to the reasons stated in the standard*. (additional section processing rules, which if you're lucky someone might feel like going into)

Comment: *is it really that costly nowadays?* - I would think that is not even the top concern at this point but rather changing the requirements at all. The benefit of making that change is unclear at best (especially since `NS` and `MX` records refer to names) while it would potentially break currently deployed software. (While you put a positive spin on your own experience you had apparently yourself noticed it causing problems, so "everything already works with the new requirements" doesn't seem to hold up in this case even just based on your own experience.)

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but google, facebook and even yahoo (who are mail service providers) all provide MX records pointing to other CNAME records.  In fact, I cannot recall ever seeing any MX records point straight to an IP address.  Is this strange that everyone is just blindly ignoring the standards? or am i misunderstanding something?